# How to plot cross-sections of imshow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, imshow

I am doing numerical simulations in python 3.6 and trying to inspect cross-sections of 2d imshow. I made the horizontal inspection and would like to have vertical, but got into some difficulties. The blue inspection lines correspond to 'bottom' (horizontal) and 'left' (vertical) subplots. Example code (I haven't been allowed to attach a matplotlib image):

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Array = np.random.rand(100, 100)
grid_points = 100

fig_mpl, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10, 10), facecolor = 'white')

line = ax.imshow(Array, cmap = 'hot')
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size = "5%", pad = 0.05)
caxb = divider.append_axes("bottom", size = "10%", pad = 0.05)
caxl = divider.append_axes("left", size = "10%", pad = 0.05)

bar = fig_mpl.colorbar(line, cax = cax, orientation = 'vertical') 
ax.axhline(grid_points/2)
ax.axvline(grid_points/2)      

X = np.linspace(0, grid_points - 1, grid_points)      
projb, = caxb.plot(X, Array[int(grid_points/2)], color = 'red')
projl, = caxl.plot(X, Array[:, int(grid_points/2)], color = 'red')

caxb.set_ylim(-0.1*np.max(Array), 1.1*np.max(Array))
caxb.set_xlim(0, grid_points - 1)
caxl.set_xlim(-0.1*np.max(Array), 1.1*np.max(Array))
caxl.set_ylim(0, grid_points - 1)

ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
caxb.set_xticks([])
caxl.set_yticks([])
caxb.set_yticks([np.min(Array), np.max(Array)])
caxl.set_xticks([np.min(Array), np.max(Array)])
caxb.yaxis.tick_right()

for tick in caxl.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(-90)

caxb.grid(color = 'black', marker = 8)
caxl.grid(color = 'black', marker = 8)

fig_mpl.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0)
fig_mpl.tight_layout()
```

I want *projl* to plot the cross-section of *Array* in vertical *caxl*.
Is there any proper way to do the thing?

Comment: "I haven't been allowed to attach an image" - Assuming you mean an image of your code, then you shouldn't be trying to attach screenshots of code in the first place. Images of code are a major hassle and [are liable to get you downvoted](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) for the reasons described in the link. Posting supplemental images are fine, but your code examples should be posted as text in the question/answer you're making, like you did here.

Comment: I meant matplotlib image. StackOverflow has restricted posting images for users with less than 10 reputation. But thanks for clarifying the text!

Comment: That makes sense - The way the statement was parenthesized along with saying you'd post your code, it sounded like you were trying post an image of code, which is something that new users seem prone to do.

Comment: @SergeKonstantinov  - post the matplotlib picture link in the comments and I will include it in your question. Mind you that I will only get a notification if you @ me, when writing the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
projl, = caxl.plot(X, Array[:, int(grid_points/2)], color = 'red')
```

you need

```
projl, = caxl.plot(Array[:, int(grid_points/2)], X, color = 'red')
```

because the amplitude should be shown along the horizontal (x-) axis and the grid index (`X`) along the vertical (y-) axis.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, thanks! I did it even before posting, but for some reason it wasn't helpful.